# Is this the right way to get the grand total of processors with WMI on a multi-cpu system?

Tags: c#, wmi, processors

I don't have access to a multi-socketed computer, so I am unsure if the following will get the grand total of processors and logical processors.  I assume ManagementObjectSearcher will return an instance for each socketed CPU and I just keep a running total?

```
int totalCPUs = 0;
int totalLogicalCPUs = 0;

ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");
foreach (var mo in mos.Get())
{
    string num = mo.Properties["NumberOfProcessors"].Value.ToString();
    totalCPUs += Convert.ToInt32(num);


    num = mo.Properties["NumberOfLogicalProcessors"].Value.ToString();
    totalLogicalCPUs += Convert.ToInt32(num);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't, but your code will still work when it is run on a massively parallel multi-machine cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It will only return 1 instance of Win32_ComputerSystem. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=VS.85).aspx):

> If a computer system has two physical processors each containing two logical processors, then the value of NumberOfProcessors is 2 and NumberOfLogicalProcessors is 4. The processors may be multicore or they may be hyperthreading processors.